# "NSString stringWithFormat:" with "%zd" curious behavior in 32bit devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, 32-bit, stringwithformat

Why we cannot format string using "%zd" as expected in 32bit devices(iPhone5, iPhone4s or their simulators)?

```
int64_t test1 = 11111111;
int64_t test2 = 22222222;
int64_t test3 = 33333333;
int64_t test4 = 44444444;
NSString *testStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%zd %zd %zd %zd\"", test1, test2, test3, test4];
NSLog(@"testStr: %@", testStr);

NSInteger test5 = 55555555;
NSInteger test6 = 66666666;
NSInteger test7 = 77777777;
NSInteger test8 = 88888888;
testStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%zd %zd %zd %zd\"", test5, test6, test7, test8];
NSLog(@"testStr: %@", testStr);
```

The log is:

```
2017-09-12 05:53:59.462: testStr:"11111111 0 22222222 0"
2017-09-12 05:53:59.465: testStr:"55555555 66666666 77777777 88888888"
```

Answer (score 3):

*Note: Answer just typed in on a tablet, your sample not tested, so this is a guess.*

The format `%zd` is for values of type `size_t` and not 64-bit values.

Try using `%lld` for `int64_t` values, `long long` is 64 bits on both 32-bit and 64-bit iOS versions.

For `NSInteger` try `%ld` and cast the arguments to `long`, this is because the size of `NSInteger` is dependent on platform.

HTH

Comment: Think you for your reply.
Sorry for the slow response.
I know what you say, and you answer is damn right. But I still do not know why the behavious so mysterious (Look at the first out put).

Comment: When arguments are passed to a *variable argument* function/method, such as `stringWithFormat:` the *bytes* of each argument value are placed on the stack contiguously. The variable `test1` is 64-bits, so 8-bytes are placed on the stack, these are followed by the 8 bytes of `test2`, etc. On 32-bit `%zd` formats a 32-bit value, so for each occurrence of `%zd` in the format string 4 bytes off the stack are used. When the decimal value `11111111` is written as a 64-bit binary number the top 32-bits all `0`. So the 8-bytes of `test1` get formatted as two 4-byte values, the second of which is `0`.

Comment: It sound reasonable! Thank you VERY MUCH. And, where can I learn this? it's interesting knowledge that I do not know about.

Comment: Seeking knowledge is always good! Two sources you can research: you can investigate the ABI of the compiler/cpu/OS you are using; and you can read about code generation in a book on compilers. For example the classic *Compilers* by Aho & Ullman, aka the *Dragon Book*, describes the calling sequence with mention of variable argument functions such as C's `printf()`, though as it was published over a decade ago it is getting "old" by computer science standards! ;-)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right directions. It's my honor to have you great answers.